# ffmpeg - blend video with images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, effects

So I want to create videos that had a red overlay, effect and I assume that `blend` is the right options filter for this. Here my command :

```
ffmpeg -i dogs.mp4 -i red.jpg -filter_complex '[1:v]scale=1280:720[ckout];[0:v][ckout]blend=all_mode='multiply'[out]' -map '[out]' output.mp4
```

But when i tried this I always got :

```
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 00000263f19a9560] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[Parsed_blend_1 @ 00000263f192fa20] First input link top parameters (size 1920x1080, SAR 0:1) do not match the corresponding second input link bottom parameters (1280x720, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_blend_1 @ 00000263f192fa20] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_blend_1
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

What is the right command for this?

Comment: Do you want to add a red tint on top?

Comment: @Gyan Yes, I'm blending red tint png actually and, overlay it on top of video with multiply rule

Comment: As Gyan's answer indicates, any filter involving two or more videos being put together in any way, requires that those videos have the same resolutions. Exceptions would be filters like the vstack where only one line of the resolutions need to match. Scale red.jpg before starting the blend. Several ways to do this, Gyan's solution being pretty handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blend filter requires both inputs to have the same resolution. You can use the scale2ref filter to resize the overlay.

`ffmpeg -i dogs.mp4 -i red.jpg -filter_complex '[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ckout][vid];[vid][ckout]blend=all_mode='multiply'[out]' -map '[out]' output.mp4`

Comment: `scale2ref` That's a handy filter. So it scales the res of the first input `[1:v]` to match the second `[0:v]`?

Comment: Yes, it just gives access to the attributes of a reference video. The target size does not have to be the same as the reference. That's the behaviour of the default values. See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref

Comment: Hmm, interesting, the scale works but the error still happens `First input link top parameters (size 1920x1080, SAR 0:1) do not match the corresponding second input link bottom parameters (1920x1080, SAR 1:1)` `Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_blend_1` I'm using 3.4.

Comment: I got it working with this. `ffmpeg -i red.jpg -i dogs.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref[a][b];[a]setdar=16/9[c];[b]setdar=16/9[d];[c][d]blend=all_mode=overlay:all_opacity=1[out]" -map "[out]" output6.mp4` actually your command should be right. 


can't edit my comment because of StackOverflow so I add a new one

Comment: Recent versions of ffmpeg blend filter no longer require matching aspect ratios.